# Protractor dismissing alert popups

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I got an Employee create page, I fill in the details and click the 'Save' button, an alert pops up saying 'Employee created successfully' and the page changes to the Employee list page. The Alert disappears after 8 seconds. I am able to validate the 'Employee created successfully' text, but when I try to close the popup it says No element found

This is the popup code

```
<div class="alert ng-scope top-left am-fade alert-info" ng-class="[type ? 'alert-' + type : null]" style="display: block;">
<button class="close ng-scope" ng-click="$hide()" ng-if="dismissable" type="button">×</button>
<strong class="ng-binding" ng-bind="title"></strong>
<span class="ng-binding" ng-bind-html="content">Employee created successfully</span>
```

This is the error I get

```
Failed: No element found using locator: By.cssSelector("[ng-click=\"$hide()\"]")
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem with dismissable element, I solve it adding this line before use the element, (maybe you will need add a browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(eleme)))

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

`browser.switchTo().alert().accept();`

or

`browser.switchTo().alert().dimiss();`

Comment: yes I did and I got this error - Failed: No alert is present (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Comment: have you tried the locator 

[by.buttonText](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.buttonText)

Comment: unfortunately that didnt work as well - Failed: No element found using locator: by.buttonText("×")

Answer (score 0):

This is not a kind of alert you can or should catch `browser.switchTo().alert()`.

Instead, the idea here is to *wait for the popup to appear and click the `button` element inside*:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

var popup = element(by.css("div.alert"));

// wait for the popup to appear
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(popup), 10000);

// make the expectation
expect(popup.element(by.binding("content")).getText()).toEqual("Employee created successfull");

// click the button
popup.element(by.tagName("button")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var logOutBtn = element(by.css('button[ng-click="$hide()"]'));
logOutBtn.click();
```